# What control should I use for this UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm relatively new to WPF, so could anyone give me some guidelines on how to build this UI (it's main panel of Paint on Windows)
[image]

I prefer code style over XAML (just for the learning purpose), so a general idea on what controls should be used would be more than enough, I can handle the detail of each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are online templates. I think that you are searching for [**Ribbon Control Template**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/03/introducing-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf.aspx).
Then, [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23199/WPF-C-Ribbon-Control-Library) has a great article about this.

You can check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534.aspx) msdn article, too.

In these links you have a lot of examples.

To use it you will create a new project with an online template, like in the image bellow (you see: it's selected *WPF Ribbon Application*:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

That is a Ribbon control. 
You can check this out: I[ntroducing Microsoft Ribbon for WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2010/08/03/introducing-microsoft-ribbon-for-wpf.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Probably want to use the Ribbon Control? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877

Answer (score 1):

When I had the same question in my mind, I did an analysis of all ribbon controls and collected their links.

Here are they

http://fluent.codeplex.com/

http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview&ProjectName=wpf

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877

Code Project Links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24062/A-Demonstration-for-WPF-Ribbon-Control-Library
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23199/WPF-C-Ribbon-Control-Library
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23343/A-Graphical-WPF-Ribbon-Control-Builder